# Binary Search - Best and worst case

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

In an exam I see a question:

> Which one of the following is true?
>
> 1. For a binary search, the best-case occurs when the target item is in the beginning of the search list.
> 2. For a binary search, the best-case occurs when the target is at the end of the search list.
> 3. For a binary search, the worst-case is when the target item is not in the search list.
> 4. For a binary search, the worst-case is when the target is found in the middle of the search list.

Well in my point of view both **1.** and **3.** are correct but it's only asking for one option. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**3.** is indeed correct, as you will need to go through the algorithm and terminate at the "worst" stop clause, where the list is empty, needed `log(n)` iterations.

**1.** is not correct. The best case is NOT when the first element is the target, it is when the middle element is the target, as you compare the middle element to the target, not the first element, so if the middle element is the target - the algorithm will finish in one iteration.

Answer (score 0):

I think **1.** is not correct. For each iteration, we compare the middle item of the current search list with the target. So if the target item is at the beginning of the search list, we need the maximum search time.

Answer (score 0):

If we are assuming that the search list is sorted then option 3 will be correct, because each time we divide list into two parts and we go for one part out of two. With this we get `log n` level. If element is not found then it takes `O(log n)` to check which is worst case of binary search.

If the list is not sorted and we want to apply binary search then first we have to sort the list.
We can search element with doing insertion sort. In that case 1 & 3 will both be correct.

**Correctness of option 1:**

When we insert first element from list and at that time we check whether this matches a given element or not - if it matched then it will be best case `O(1)`.

**Correctness of option 3:**

If we go through through all element in list with doing sorting and searching and still haven't found the element then it will be wort case `O(n²)`.

Comment: It is common with binary search to require the list to be sorted.  If sorting beforehand is required that's a separate operation that is not included, even if you need to account for it in your total application time.